# Android - ASyncTask Error ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to download files in the background. I didn't change anything having to do with the file downloading or the asynctask, and all of a sudden it no longer worked. Here's my LogCat:

```
    03-04 17:51:45.485: W/System.err(1481): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    03-04 17:51:45.485: W/System.err(1481):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
     03-04 17:51:45.485: W/System.err(1481):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
     03-04 17:51:45.485: W/System.err(1481):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
     03-04 17:51:45.485: W/System.err(1481):    ... 14 more
     03-04 17:51:45.765: W/dalvikvm(1481): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4af3b90)
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): Process: com.csc.android.industryforum, PID: 1481
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:64)
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:122)
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:59)
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):    at com.csc.android.industryforum.MainActivity.readFileArray(MainActivity.java:902)
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):    at com.csc.android.industryforum.MainActivity.handleMenuInfo(MainActivity.java:355)
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):    at com.csc.android.industryforum.MainActivity.access$1(MainActivity.java:342)
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):    at com.csc.android.industryforum.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1023)
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):    at com.csc.android.industryforum.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
     03-04 17:51:45.865: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):    ... 4 more
     03-04 17:51:46.485: I/Choreographer(1481): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
     03-04 17:51:46.925: I/Choreographer(1481): Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.csc.android.industryforum.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b4dcd940 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-424,140} that was originally added here
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:346)
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481):     at com.csc.android.industryforum.MainActivity.loadFiles(MainActivity.java:136)
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481):     at com.csc.android.industryforum.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:99)
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
     03-04 17:51:48.615: E/WindowManager(1481):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

According to one of the answers, the problem is with my file reading, so here's the code:

```
private ArrayList<String> readFileArray(File file){
    FileInputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = openFileInput(file.getName());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);//this is line 902
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    String line;
    String line1 = "";
    ArrayList<String> ar1 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    try {
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            ar1.add(line);
            if (line1.equals("")){
                line1 = line1 + line;
            }else{
            line1 = line1 + "\n" + line;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ar1;

}
```

And here's the code that calls that code:

```
    private String[] handleMenuInfo(String selection){
    DataClass dc = new DataClass(this);

    File dir = getDir("myDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File file = new File(dir, selection + ".txt");
    ArrayList <String> menuArray;

        menuArray = readFileArray(file);
        String[] menuList = menuArray.toArray(new String[menuArray.size()]);
        return menuList;
    //}

}
```

Here's the ASyncTask

```
 private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

    private Context context;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    public DownloadTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

     protected void onPostExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... sUrl) {

            DataClass dc = new DataClass(c);
            //ArrayList<String> menuArray = dc.getMenuArray("Home");
            String[] menuArray = {"Home", "Announcements", "Speakers", "Events", "Exhibitors", "Agenda", "Hotels", "Documents"}; 
            File dir = getDir("myDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            for(int i=1; i <= 7; i++){
                String[] menuList = handleMenuInfo(menuArray[i]);
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                mProgressDialog.setMax(7);
                mProgressDialog.setProgress(i);
                for(int i2=1; i2 < menuList.length; i2++){
                File file = new File(dir, menuArray[i]  + "/" + menuList[i2] + ".txt");
                ArrayList<String> viewArray = dc.getInfoArray(menuArray[i],menuList[i2]);
                writeToFile(file, viewArray);

                }
            }
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
            Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("new", "No");
            editor.commit();
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
       return null;


        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Do you see the error saying there is no such file or directory? Are you sure you are downloading a file from an existing location? I would check that to make sure you are not hitting a dead end.

Comment: Check if the file path is correct.

Comment: Code added per request.

Comment: @DanCuc The directory I'm saving it to is appearing as:path /data/data/com.csc.android.myapp/app_myDir/file.txt"

This does seem strange. It should end in Documents, not app_myDir. Oh wait! I think I found the issue.

Comment: Neermind, I got confused with the directory structure for the iOS version.

Comment: Okay, I think I know what the problem is, but I don't know how I can fix it.

The ASyncTask is downloading files needed for the app to operate. Since it is running in parallel to the rest of the app, the app is looking for files that have not yet been downloaded. I guess I need to pause the main thread or stop it from calling the needed files.

Comment: Fixed it, see the below comment on the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based purely off of the stack trace you've provided, it appears that you're encountering [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417741/nullpointerexception-lock-null). In `MainActivity.DownloadTask`, you're passing an uninitialized `FileInputStream` into the `InputStreamReader`.

The problem resides around the instantiation of your `InputStream` being used in `MainActivity`, line 902.

Comment: I have not touched that method in quite some time. I've added the relevant code however. I have no idea what could have caused this change. You are right though, at line 902 it stops and does not continue to line 903. It does continue with later code for some reason, which I find strange.

Comment: Fixed it. The ASyncTask is for downloading files necessary for the app. Originally the app checked the server every time it changed views, but this was too slow. Instead I downloaded all files from the start of the app. There remained one line calling the "get from internet" code and slowing the app down. Once removed it was checking the hard drive for the file. Uninstalling then reinstalling meant the files were missing and it was crashing when it tried to load them before being downloaded. Now if the files haven't been downloaded it gets it from the internet instead. Problem solved.