# Unable To Login in Android

Tags: php, android

I am making an application where the user needs to log in from the android login form.
But when i click on the login button, i get the error which is given below.

Following is the java source code (Investor.java):

```
package com.example.entrepreneurexpress;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Investors extends Activity {

    StringBuffer buffer;
    InputStream inputStream;
    String result = null;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.investors_index);
        ActionBar aBar = getActionBar();
        aBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        final EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtemailAddress);
        final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);

        final SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        Button btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (email.length() >= 1) {
                    email.setText("");
                }
                if (password.length() >= 1) {
                    password.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

        Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String emailAdd = email.getText().toString();
                String pasWord = password.getText().toString();

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("emailAdd", emailAdd);
                editor.putString("password", pasWord);
                editor.commit();

                try {
                    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://hostname.com/AdroidApp/select.php");

                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserEmail", emailAdd));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", pasWord));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

                    Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeInvestor.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }

                try{
                     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                     String line = null;
                     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                         sb.append(line + "\n");                                
                     }
                     inputStream.close();
                     result=sb.toString();
                 } catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                 }
                try {
                     JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                     CharSequence w = (CharSequence) json_data.get("re");
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), w, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
            }
        });

        Button btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.investorRegister);
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent invRegister = new Intent(Investors.this,
                        InvestorRegister.class);
                startActivity(invRegister);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here's the source code for php (select.php):

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "EntrepreneurExpress");

    if (!$con) {
        die('Connection Aborted ! <br />' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    $email = $_POST['emailAdd'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM Brokers WHERE EmailID = '".$email."' AND password = '".$password."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Some Error: " . mysqli_error($con));

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $r["re"] = "Welcome !";
        print(json_encode($r));
        echo "Y";
    } else {
        $r["re"] = "Bye ! " .mysqli_error($con);
        print(json_encode($r));
        echo "<br />N";
    }

?>
```

Here's the error that I am getting:

```
04-12 23:22:16.817: E/log_tag(15132): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
```

Kindly help me out with this. Thanks.

Comment: `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);` this is returning null

Comment: so what am i suppose to do ?? and can u please explain in more detail..

Comment: Check if that is not null ? `if(response != null){ //rest of the code }else{ //response failed, debug why }`

Comment: still the same error..

Answer (score 0):

Can you first put a breakpoint on the following line of your code and run in debugger mode?

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"),8);
```

I would be interested if the inputStream is null.

Also, another similar question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417741/nullpointerexception-lock-null)